# c++ argmax of function(vector)

Tags: c++, argmax

I have a `vector<int> v{1, 2, 3}`

I have a function: `int square(int x){return x*x;}`

My question is: **How do properly I find the `argmax` (in `v`) of `square(v)` ?**

In this case `9` is bigger than `4` and `1`. Hence result should give `3`.

I could play with indices of `"square(v)"` and then use that index to retrieve the element in `v`. But maybe there is a c++ built-in function or a more elegant way to proceed?

Comment: Thanks @Mat. I did not find it before posting. It solved my problem. Just for information, here is one solution adapted from this answer:

`std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};`

`auto argMax = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b){return a*a < b*b;});`

`std::cout << "argmax (square(v)) = " << *argMax << std::endl;`